# How to do search for a specific set of data by using a filter

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphql, graphene-python, flask-graphql

I have a tag model and I would like to search for a specific tag with a specific name. Here is what I have so far.

```
from datetime import datetime
from graphene_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemyObjectType,SQLAlchemyConnectionField
from database.base import db_session
from database.models.model_post import ModelPost
from database.models.model_image import ModelImage
from database.models.model_posttag  import PostsTags
from database.models.model_tag import ModelTag
from database.models.model_user import ModelUser
from database.models.model_locale import ModelLocale
import graphene
from helpers import utils


# Create a generic class to mutualize description of user attributes for both queries and mutations
class TagAttribute:
    name = graphene.String(description="Tag Name")
    isactive = graphene.Boolean(description="is active")


class Tag(SQLAlchemyObjectType):
    """Tag node."""

    class Meta:
        model = ModelTag
        interfaces = (graphene.relay.Node,)

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    tagToFind = graphene.Field(lambda: Tag, name=graphene.String())

    def resolve_find_tag(self, info, **kwargs):
        query = Tag.get_query(info)
        name = kwargs.get("name")
        return query.filter(TagModel.name == name).first()

class CreateTagInput(graphene.InputObjectType, TagAttribute):
    """Arguments to create a tag."""
    pass


class CreateTag(graphene.Mutation):
    """Mutation to create a tag."""
    tag = graphene.Field(lambda: Tag, description="tag created by this mutation.")

    class Arguments:
        input = CreateTagInput(required=True)

    def mutate(self, info, input):
        data = utils.input_to_dictionary(input)
        data['created_at'] = datetime.utcnow()
        data['updated_at'] = datetime.utcnow()

        tag = ModelTag(**data)
        db_session.add(tag)
        db_session.commit()

        return CreateTag(tag=tag)


class UpdateTagInput(graphene.InputObjectType, TagAttribute):
    """Arguments to update a tag."""
    id = graphene.ID(required=True, description="Global Id of the tag.")


class UpdateTag(graphene.Mutation):
    """Update a tag."""
    tag = graphene.Field(lambda: Tag, description="tag updated by this mutation.")

    class Arguments:
        input = UpdateTagInput(required=True)

    def mutate(self, info, input):
        data = utils.input_to_dictionary(input)
        data['updated_at'] = datetime.utcnow()

        tag = db_session.query(ModelTag).filter_by(id=data['id'])
        tag.update(data)
        db_session.commit()
        tag = db_session.query(ModelTag).filter_by(id=data['id']).first()

        return UpdateTag(tag=tag)
```

Here is a query that I have

```
query FindTagByName($name: String ="searchstring"){
  findTag(name: $name) {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

but I am getting this error

[image]

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong here ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your `Query` has `tagToFind` fileld (that should be in snake case) but you resolve a `find_tag` so graphene couldn't find it.

Change `tagToFind` to `find_tag` to fix it.